# Azure mobile service - accessing a table controller from another custom controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to access a table using its controller from another controller method.
But when the method tries to call the table controller method I get an exception:
   `Exception=System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.TableController.....`

- I manage to access the table controller method from the web API and execute it successfully.
- I tried the same thing with TodoItem given as an example by the initial mobile service.
- After several publishes to the server trying to fix the issue the web API stopped working and I get this exception : `An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
  Additional information: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)` I managed to solve it when I reopened a mobile service and database with the exact same code that didn't work.

Any tips ?

Here is my table controller created by the controller wizard:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using FringProjectMobileService.DataObjects;
using FringProjectMobileService.Models;

namespace FringProjectMobileService.Controllers
{
    public class StorageItemController : TableController<StorageItem>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            FringProjectMobileServiceContext context = new FringProjectMobileServiceContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<StorageItem>(context, Request, Services);
        }

        // GET tables/StorageItem
        public IQueryable<StorageItem> GetAllStorageItem()
        {
            return Query(); 
        }

        // GET tables/StorageItem/xxxxxxxxxx
        public SingleResult<StorageItem> GetStorageItem(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }

        // PATCH tables/StorageItem/xxxxxxxx
        public Task<StorageItem> PatchStorageItem(string id, Delta<StorageItem> patch)
        {
             return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }

        // POST tables/StorageItem
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostStorageItem(StorageItem item)
        {
            StorageItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }

        // DELETE tables/StorageItem/xxxxxxxxxx
        public Task DeleteStorageItem(string id)
        {
             return DeleteAsync(id);
        }

    }
}
```

Below the other controller code trying to access the method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;


namespace FringProjectMobileService.Controllers
{
    public class ArduinoController : ApiController
    {
        public ApiServices Services { get; set; }

        // GET api/Arduino
        public string Get()
        {
            Services.Log.Info("Hello from custom controller!");
            return "Hello";
        }


        public async void PostProcessTag(String id)
        {
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient client = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient("http://some-service.azure-mobile.net", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IMobileServiceTable<DataObjects.StorageItem> storage_item_table = client.GetTable<DataObjects.StorageItem>();
            await storage_item_table.ToEnumerableAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried a different implementation for the method :

```
        public void PostProcessTag(String id)
        {
            StorageItemController table_controller = new StorageItemController();
            IQueryable<DataObjects.StorageItem> item = table_controller.GetAllStorageItem();
        }
```

The service context:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Tables;

namespace FringProjectMobileService.Models
{
    public class FringProjectMobileServiceContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to alter your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        // For more information refer to the documentation:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx
        //
        // To enable Entity Framework migrations in the cloud, please ensure that the 
        // service name, set by the 'MS_MobileServiceName' AppSettings in the local 
        // Web.config, is the same as the service name when hosted in Azure.

        private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

        public FringProjectMobileServiceContext() : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        } 

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            string schema = ServiceSettingsDictionary.GetSchemaName();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema))
            {
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema);
            }

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
                new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                    "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FringProjectMobileService.DataObjects.StorageItem> StorageItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same error for the two approaches? What do you get if you go the `new StorageItemController()` route?

Comment: Yea the same error. 
 
I managed to make it work, I don't know why but when I created the project from scratch the problem was resolved.

But now when I try to open another table I get the same errors, it seems that whenever I add a table controller something get broken

Comment: Why not just use a DomainManager or DBContext in your API controller instead of using the TableController? I get that you want reuse, but that controller is the HTTP front end for the DomainManager and built to handle the interaction between the HTTP request infrastructure and the domain manager.